# ESP32 Cam with P2P WiFi connection with Android

Tags: esp32

I am newly experimenting with WiFi module ESP32 CAM, and I found that it works "well".

My problems are a high latency, but there are many devices connected to my home network.
I have seen videos and it seems even at 1600x1200 ther can be got over 10fps, but I got no more than 5 on HVGA.

I have a couple of old commercial WiFi cameras which have a P2P mode, where the camera generates its own WiFi and you can connect (i.e.) via Android App to the WiFi of the camera directly and  see the image and change some parameters.

I have searched but I do not found any code or idea for the ESP32.

I would be very grateful if somebody can help me in any way.